# Fatal Error-in my controller

Tags: php

Fatal error: Call to a member function insert_slider() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\tulip\application\controllers\slider.php on line 19

this is my controller:

class Slider extends CI_Controller{

```
public function __construct(){
parent::__construct();
$this->load->library('upload');
$this->load->database();
$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
//$this->load->library('session');
}



public function add_slider(){

    $data = array('slider_name' => $this->input->post('title'),'desc'=>$this->input->post('desc'));        
    $slider_id= $this->slider_model->insert_slider($data);
    @$data=$this->do_upload($slider_id,'image1');
    $this->resizer('../sliders/'.$data['file_name'],192,300,'thumb1');
    //$this->resizer('../sliders/'.$data['file_name'],60,300,'thumb2');
    //$this->view_movie($movie_id);

    $this->view_slider($slider_id);
    }//end else
```

}

And my model is:

```
public function __construct(){
parent::__construct();
}

public function insert_slider($data){
$this->load->database();
$this->db->insert('slider', $data);
$id= $this->db->insert_id();
$this->db->where('slider_id',$id);
$this->db->update('slider',array('position'=>$id));
return $id;
}
```

}

What is the error, I still cannot find it?

Comment: may you couldn't include the slider_model model

Comment: I have given my names for rest of the controllers in same way

Comment: just try once include the model

Answer (score 2):

I think you missed your model  try to load in your  constructor or your add_slider funciton

```
$this->load->model('slider_model');
```